# How to navigate and pass data to another view controller without use of segue in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hy, I am new to swift. I have on question. I have one view controller in which have a textbox and button and similarly I have second view controller which have a textbox and button. I want to do that whenever I pressed button of first view controller The second view controller appear and data of textbox of first view controller will pass to the textbox of second view controller but without the use of segue.
Please help me.

Comment: Please put some code in question and people will help you faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In FirstViewController.swift**

```
@IBAction weak var textFiled: UITextField!

@IBAction func sendDatatoNextVC(sender: UIButton) {
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let vc : SecondViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewControllerSBID”) as SecondViewController
vc. recevedString  = textFiled.text
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**In SecondViewController.swift**

```
var recevedString: String =  “”

@IBAction weak var textFiled2: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
textFiled2.text = recevedString

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` if you don't want to use `segue`.

Consider below code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let someViewConroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewControllerID") as! SomeViewController
someViewConroller.someObject = yourObject  //here you can assign object to SomeViewController
self.presentViewController(someViewConroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Yes you can put this code in `IBAction` and you need to create `someObject` in your `SomeViewController` which will hold your previous view controller's value.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
if you creating custom  view controller.

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IDEInterface", bundle: nil)
var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IDENavController") as! MyCustomViewController

controller.exercisedPassed = "Ex1"

self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

In first VC ,

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

    vc.detail =  [name,age,sal]

   self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In second VC ,

var detail:[String]?